# AWS Lambda scheduled event source via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda

I already have my lambda / roles defined in cloudformation and would love to also use it to add a scheduled eventsources ... are there any docs or examples around ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [Aws::Event::Rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html) with a `ScheduleExpression` and a `AWS::Lambda::Permission`

```
// rule to periodically call the lambda
"TagWatcherRule": {
  "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
  "Properties": {
    "ScheduleExpression": "rate(10 minutes)",
    "Targets": [
      {
        "Id": "TagWatcherScheduler",
        "Arn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "TagWatcherFunction",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
// role may call the lambda
"InvokeLambdaPermission": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
  "Properties": {
    "FunctionName": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "TagWatcherFunction",
        "Arn"
      ]
    },
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "Principal": "events.amazonaws.com",
    "SourceArn": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "TagWatcherRule",
        "Arn"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: According to the docs, ScheduleExpression needs to be plural minutes not minute.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ScheduledEvents.html

Comment: @timmah.faase Not true? "Valid values: minute | minutes | hour | hours | day | days"

Comment: You're allowed singular on "1", e.g. "1 minute", but must use plural otherwise, e.g. "10 minutes". Grammar is enforced!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a bunch of times. I'm certain you just saved me hours of my life.

Comment: How can we pass custom input to lambda function through event rule?

Comment: @nff you can pass custom input by adding an attribute to the Target definition: so in this example it would be ```{
        "Id": "TagWatcherScheduler",
        "Arn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "TagWatcherFunction",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }, "Input": "{'hello': 'world'}"
      }```

Answer (score 11):

I solved same problem.

```
"RoleForLambdaStopEC2Instances" : {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Policies": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "LambdaStopEC2InstancesPolicy",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Path": "/"
  }
},
"LambdaStopEC2Instances": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Code": {
      "S3Bucket": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "S3Key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "Handler": "stopEC2Instances.handler",
    "Role": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["RoleForLambdaStopEC2Instances", "Arn"] },
    "Runtime": "nodejs4.3",
    "Timeout": "5"
  }
},
"StopEC2InstancesRule": {
  "Type" : "AWS::Events::Rule",
  "Properties" : {
    "Name" : "StopEC2Instances",
    "ScheduleExpression" : "cron(0 13 ? * MON-FRI *)",
    "State": "ENABLED",
    "Targets": [{
      "Arn": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaStopEC2Instances", "Arn"] },
      "Id": "stopEC2Instances"
    }]
  }
},
"LambdaInvokePermission": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
  "Properties": {
    "FunctionName" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["LambdaStopEC2Instances", "Arn"] },
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "Principal": "events.amazonaws.com",
    "SourceAccount": { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" },
    "SourceArn": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["StopEC2InstancesRule","Arn"] }
  }
}
```

Comment: In LambdaInvokePermission the SourceAccount property stopped it running for me

Comment: same as @jhanson, I had to remove the SourceArn line in LambdaInvokePermission

Answer (score 10):

The YAML Version

```
ScheduledRule: 
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties: 
    Description: "ScheduledRule"
    ScheduleExpression: "rate(10 minutes)"
    State: "ENABLED"
    Targets: 
      - 
        Arn: 
          Fn::GetAtt: 
            - "LambdaFunction"
            - "Arn"
        Id: "TargetFunctionV1"
PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda: 
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties: 
    FunctionName: 
      Ref: "LambdaFunction"
    Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
    SourceArn: 
      Fn::GetAtt: 
        - "ScheduledRule"
        - "Arn"
```

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, configuring scheduled event sources for lambda functions is currently not supported by CloudFormation.  You will need to deploy your lambda using CloudFormation and then manually configure your scheduled events.

CloudFormation does support an `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping` resource type.  However, this resource is limited configuring Kinesis or DynamoDB streams, so this is likely not helpful to you.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html

---

**Update - as of April 2016, this is now supported using CloudWatch Events - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/04/amazon-cloudwatch-events-now-supported-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/

Answer (score 4):

As of this week (18 April 2016) it is now possible to add a scheduled CloudWatch event rule that will trigger your Lambda function.

The [AWS::Event::Rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html) has a `ScheduleExpression` field for the cron-style schedule and a `Targets` array which can accept a Lambda function ARN.

Answer (score 1):

[AWS supports periodic run through sourcedetails](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-config-configrule-source-sourcedetails.html).

```
 EventSource: "aws.config"
 MaximumExecutionFrequency: Twelve_Hours
 MessageType: "ScheduledNotification"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use function name as

```
"FunctionName": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "TagWatcherFunction",
        "Arn"
      ]
    }
```

and you not specify the function then it'll throw you
"Template is not valid: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource TagWatcherFunction"

So instead of function name you can directly specify the "lambda ARN".
you can see example below

```
"TagWatcherRule": {
  "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
  "Properties": {
    "ScheduleExpression": "rate(10 minutes)",
    "Targets": [
      {
        "Id": "TagWatcherScheduler",
        "Arn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "TagWatcherFunction",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
// role may call the lambda
"InvokeLambdaPermission": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
  "Properties": {
    "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<awsid>:function:<lambd name>",
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "Principal": "events.amazonaws.com",
    "SourceArn": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "TagWatcherRule",
        "Arn"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```